# problem with .htaccess and host URL " i create " in system32 with xampp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, host, hosts

i have a problem it in the direction in URLs ..

i create me new URL in xampp

pro_mvc.com

and i want to write in .htaccess this code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -Multiviews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /mvc_pro/public
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

and i have public inside the mvc_pro in my htdocs is

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc_pro\public
```

and i create my mvc_pro.com rather localhost in

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

with this code

```
127.0.0.1 mvc_pro.com
```

and in apache code is in

```
C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
```

have

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc_pro"
    ServerName mvc_pro.com

</VirtualHost>
```

if i want to write any thing after mvc_pro.com/public like mvc_pro.com/public/qwjleqweuqwe he not turn me to index.php " and i have this file in my path " why he tell me

```
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
mvc_pro.com
Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0i PHP/7.2.10
```

thanks again !

Comment: Have you set `AllowOverride All` in the Apache config?

Comment: where i can find it to see if i add it or no ?

Answer (score 0):

`AllowOverride` directive is used to allow the use of `.htaccess` within the web server to allow overriding of the Apache config.

1. Ensure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled in `httpd.conf`. For XAMPP, it should be enabled
   by default.
2. Set `AllowOverride All` in `httpd-vhosts.conf` for the document root directory
3. Make sure to restart Apache

Your VirtualHost config should look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc_pro"
    ServerName mvc_pro.com
    <Directory C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc_pro>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: nope mr.Tristan i know the problem it was in
 RewriteBase /mvc_pro/public
i must remove it !

Answer (score 0):

in :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -Multiviews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /mvc_pro/public
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

just remove

```
RewriteBase /mvc_pro/public
```